# Why a 5 x 7 matrix A must have 2 $\leq$ nullity(A) $\leq$ 7?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Show that a 5 x 7 matrix A must have 2$\leq$ nullity(A) $\leq$ 7.

Give an example of a 5 x 7 matrix A with
nullity(A) = 2 and an example of a 5 x 7 matrix A with nullity(A) = 7.

Comment: You know the rank nullity theorem. Now what is a bound on the rank of a $5 \times 7$ matrix? Use that bound in the formula. Think of the matrix of zeros : what is its nullity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rank + Nullity = 7. Since the Rank can be as small as $0$, (e.g. the zero matrix) and as large as $5$ e.g. $$\begin{pmatrix}I&0 \\\end{pmatrix}$$
the nullity lies between $2$ and $7$.